# Replace webcam transmission with an image from the hard drive

Tags: linux, arch-linux, android, camera

I'm working with an Android app installed in my Arch Linux using the emulator Genymotion. This app is not mine and I have not access to the source code, I'm just working with it. In some part of the process, the app needs to take a photo, but I want to use instead an image located in my hard drive.

Neither the app nor Genymotion have the option to do that, so I was wondering if there is some way to replace the transmission emitted from the webcam for the local image directly on Linux. Does anyone know how to do that?